# How to increase the clickable area of a button?

Tags: html, css

I need to increase the clickable height of a button to `48px`. The button has a background color, and I want to increase the clickable height without actually setting the height of the button (i.e. the increase in clickable area should be invisible / empty space around the button). I've tried increasing the padding and setting `background-clip: content-box`, however this means that the edges of the button are no longer rounded. What is the recommended way to achieve this?

Comment: Please provide your code.

Answer (score 2):

I'd work with a pseudo element here:

```css
button {
  --clickable-space-around-button: -15px;
  position: relative;
}

button::after {
  content: "";
  left: var(--clickable-space-around-button);
  right: var(--clickable-space-around-button);
  bottom: var(--clickable-space-around-button);
  top: var(--clickable-space-around-button);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div style="padding: 20px;">
  <button onclick="console.log('clicked')">Click me</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If your issue was rounded corner then use transparent border and padding-box not content-box

```css
button {
  background:red padding-box;
  font-size:25px;
  padding:10px 20px;
  border:25px solid transparent;
  border-radius:35px;
  outline:none;
}

button:active {
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<button>text</button>
```

Comment: @connexo margin-box was never a thing for background-clip/background-origin and I doubt that padding-box is deprecated because this will make a 2 properties (that I use everyday) useless. Where did you get such information?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice you're using it on background shortcut. What is the name of the singular prop?

Comment: @connexo I am not using box-sizing property here. I am using background-clip/background-origin (note the use of padding-box inside background: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#the-background-clip

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found for your request, I hope it will be useful.

> I can suggest adding an invisible before (tinted with a color so that
> the area is visible, you just need to remove this color):

```css
.link {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin:50px auto;
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  background: pink;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.link:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: -15px;
  left: -15px;
  right: -15px;
  bottom: -15px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.06);//цвет убрать
}
```

```html
<a class="link" href="#"></a>
```

Original Answer: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/702645

*Or you also can just try margin*

Have a good day!